# How to reset some variables in a @sessionScoped Bean when refreshing in JSF2.0?

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean

Please I have a bean which has the `@sessionScoped` bean( cdi bean) as a scope. when I refresh the jsf page I notice that some of my variable are not initialized( like in the case of `@viewScoped` bean). 
How could I resolve such issue please and initialize my variables after refreshing this session scoped bean?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This is too vague a question to answer. Where are the variables coming from? Why do you use sessionscoped if you need the variables to be viewscoped? what are you currently doing to refresh, and it is not working? Where is the code definition?

Comment: Please try making a [mcve].

Comment: If you want these variables to be view scoped, just put these variables in a view scoped bean.